# Error using case, when in SQL

Tags: sql

I am following along Ben O. Smith's *Introduction to SQL for Data Scientists* but am having trouble with the following code on pg.9 on my local mysql:

PDF URL: http://downloads.bensresearch.com/SQL.pdf

**SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 's.id' in 'where clause'**

I have followed the exact same data structure listed on pg. 3. But can't wrap my head around the error.

Is there an error in the following code?

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    (select case
                when avg_gpa >= 3.5 then 2
                when avg_gpa < 3.5 and avg_gpa >= 3.0 then 1
                else 0
                end as gpa_type 
    from
        (select avg(gpa) as avg_gpa
         from term_gpa
         where id=s.id) as avg_gpa_table
    ) as gpa_type
from 
    student as s
ORDER BY 
    name ASC;
```

Comment: The book title is not a question. Please [edit] your title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your title should explain what your difficulty is, and the book title does not do so. We're also not going to go somewhere to read the book to get information needed to help you. Provide the relevant details here, in the question itself, while you're editing. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I assume you are using MySQL, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to re-write it like this...

```
select s.id
     , s.name
     , case
            when avg_gpa >= 3.5                   then 2
            when avg_gpa < 3.5 and avg_gpa >= 3.0 then 1
            else 0
        end as gpa_type 
from student as s
LEFT JOIN  (           
            select id , avg(gpa) as avg_gpa
            from term_gpa
            Group by id
           ) as avg_gpa_table
ON avg_gpa_table.id = s.id
ORDER BY s.name ASC;
```